# How do I erase a login session in PHP from my website?

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a side project website and attempting to create basic login sessions in PHP. The code I've made should destroy the session once you've been logged out and redirect you to the login screen if there's no session.

**LOGIN FORM(index2.html.php)**

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
      header("Location: https://website.com/mike-test/main.html.php"); 
    }
?>
<html lang="en-UK">
<head>
    <!- HEAD ------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/profile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/section.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/subMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/logIn.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="javaScript/logIn.js"></script>
        <!- To Be Changed! ->
        <link rel="icon" href="_Images/Logo.ico">
        <meta name="Pharmacy Project Log In" content="Pharmacy System">
        <title>Pharmacy Project</title>
</head>
<!- HEAD ------------------------------------------------------->
    <body>
        <!- BODY ------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <div id="content">
        <section> <!--Main Content here-->
                <img src="logo.png" id="logo" height="150" width="150">
            <form action="connection3.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required /><br />
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /><br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" /><label>Remember Me</label><br />
                <button><input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" /></button><br />
            </form>
        </section>
        </div>
        <footer> <!--Just a footer-->
            <p>Website made by:<br /><br />

            <script>document.write(document.title)</script> 2019-
            <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>. @ rights reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CONNECTOR TO THE DATABASE - CREATES THE SESSION(connection3.php)**

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
      header("Location: https://website.com/mike-test/main.html.php"); 
    }

if (!empty($_POST)) 
    {
        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 
            {
                // Getting submitted user data from database
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "pharmacy", "pharmacy", "pharmacy123");
                if(mysqli_connect_error()) 
                    {
                        die('Connect Error(' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_error());
                    } else
                    {               
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username, Password FROM Employee WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND Password = '" . $password . "'");

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                            {
                                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                                header('Location: https://website.com/mike-test/main.html.php');
                            } else
                            {
                                echo "user doesn't exist";
                            }
                    }
            } else
            {
                echo "Both fields are required";
            }
    }
?>
```

**HOMEPAGE(main.html.php)**

```
<html lang="en-UK">
        <?php
            session_start();
            echo $_SESSION['user'];
            if ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) 
                {} else {
                    // Redirect them to the login page
                    header("Location: https://website.com/mike-test/index2.html.php");
                }
        ?>
<head>
    <!- HEAD ------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/profile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/section.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link href="css/subMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="javaScript/logIn.js"></script>
        <!- To Be Changed! ->
        <link rel="icon" href="_Images/Logo.ico">
        <meta name="" content="Pharmacy System">
        <title>Project</title>

</head>
<!- HEAD ------------------------------------------------------->
    <body>
        <!- BODY ------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <img src="logo.png" id="logo" height="100" width="100">
        <div id="profile">
            <div id="text">
                <p id="Name">Name</p>
                <p id="status">Status</p>
            </div>
            <div id="image">
            <img src="logo.png">
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="" target="_self"><button>Settings</button></a><br />
                <form action="close.php" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" id="logout" value="logout">LogOut</button>         
                </form>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Profile Button  -->
        <nav>
        <ul id="mainMenu">
            <li><button type="button">Counter Sales</button></li>
            <li><button type="button">Dispense Drugs</button></li>    
            <li><button type="button">Stock Control</button></li>    
            <li><button type="button">Supplier Accounts</button></li>
            <li><button type="button">File Maintenance</button></li>
            <li><button type="button">Reports</button></li>    
        </ul><!--Main Menu Bar-->
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
        <section> <!--Main Content here-->
            <h1>Main Menu</h1>
            <p></p>
            <div class="grid">            
                <ul id="subMenu">
                    <li><button type="button">SubMenu1</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button">SubMenu1</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button">SubMenu1</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button">SubMenu1</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button">SubMenu1</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button">SubMenu1</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button">SubMenu1</button></li>
                </ul><!--Main Menu Bar-->
                <div style="background: blue;">
                    <p style="color: white;">Database here</p>
                <!--This is where database-->
                </div><div></div>
                <div id="actions">
                    <button type="button">SubMenu1</button>
                    <button type="button">SubMenu1</button>
                    <button type="button">SubMenu1</button>
                    <button type="button">SubMenu1</button>
                    <button type="button">SubMenu1</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
        <footer> <!--Just a footer-->
            <p>Website made by:<br /><br />

            <script>document.write(document.title)</script> 2019-
            <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>. @ rights reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**close.php**

```
unset($_SESSION['user']);
//session_destroy();
echo $_SESSION['user'];
echo "session should be terminated";
//header('Location: https://webiste.com/mike-test/index2.html.php');
?>
```

I've tried troubleshooting, and in close.php and main.html.php by echoing out `$_SESSION['user']`. on logout, the session doesn't echo out, as it gets destroyed or unset. on trying to access main.html.php through the url link manually, the `$_SESSION['user']` still exists. I've asked multiple people and lecturers for help and all of them see no problem in the code and are dumbfounded.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try having `session_start()` at the beginning of close.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to resume the session before unsetting it**

I've posted a quote below from [session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) on PHP.Net:

> session_start() creates a session **or resumes the current one** based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.

In your close.php, you're attempting to unset a session without first resuming the session on the site, you first need to call `session_start()` and then unset it.

---

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
echo $_SESSION['user'];
echo "session should be terminated";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realise that small mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your logout.php should look like this

```
// Initialize the session
   session_start();
// Unset all of the session variables
   session_unset();
   $_SESSION = array();

// Destroy the session.
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
// Redirect to login page
    header("location: /");
    exit();
```

Comment: Using both much beter `session_unset();` and `session_destroy();`

Comment: Not if the OP is using sessions for something else on the site, `unset` will suffice.

Comment: @Dlk "All sessions are expires after login out" - depends on the method, `session_destroy()` would destroy them all, yes. `unset()` would just destroy the one he wants to destroy, if he also uses sessions for something else, these won't be affected, that's my point.

Comment: @MarkOverton Note **You wont have active sessions to use** after login out, unset or destroy doesnt affects to inactive sessions. Thanks